# how to get mingw-w64 at sourceforge?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I follow exactly https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
But at sorceforge I cannot find Mingw-w64:
"3. Install Mingw-w64 via the SourceForge website. Click Mingw-w64 to download the Windows Mingw-w64 installer."
I do not want a zip file. I want the installer as mentioned in the doc.
Please help.
Pter

Comment: The distribution they suggest ships a somewhat outdated GCC: 8.x, while we already have 10.x. Check out [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) or [winlibs](http://winlibs.com/) for an up-to-date version.

Comment: Thanks. Good info.